# Performance impact of using thenXXXX vs thenXXXXAsync methods in CompletableFuture

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, java-8, completable-future

I have question about using thenXXXX and thenXXXXAsync method of JDK 8's CompletableFuture class. As per my understanding *thenApply* will use the same thread as earlier future executes and *thenApplyAsync* uses any thread from the pool.

Code_1:

```
CompletableFuture<String> cf = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> tcf.task("FIRST"), executors)
        .thenApply(a -> {
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "Thread Id - 1 " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                ////Some operations
         })
        .thenApply(a -> {
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "Thread Id - 2 " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                ////Some operations
         });
```

> Output:
>   Thread Id - 1: pool-1-thread-1
>
> Thread Id - 2: pool-1-thread-1

Code_2:

```
CompletableFuture<String> cf = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> tcf.task("FIRST"), executors)
        .thenApplyAsync(a -> {
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "Thread Id - 1 " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                ////Some operations
         }, executors)
        .thenApplyAsync(a -> {
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "Thread Id - 2 " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                ////Some operations
         }, executors);
```

> Output:
>   Thread Id - 1: pool-1-thread-2
>
> Thread Id - 2: pool-1-thread-3

Which is the best approach to use? In the Code_2, task moves from one thread to another thread. Does it impact any performance?

thanks

Comment: `thenApply` does not make a guaranty about the used thread. It might be the thread which completed this future, but it also might be the caller’s thread, e.g. when the future has been completed already, or an arbitrary other thread calling a `then…` method, if these calls and the completion happen at the same time. The question is, can you live with this lack of control, e.g. are you fine with this action happening completely in the current thread.